# What would I need to open a circuit (a usb cable) for a few seconds, on a given time?

Tags: power, usb, timer

I have a USB cable connected to a USB modem.

On a specific time of day (say, at midnight - but it should be configurable) I would like to open the circuit for a few seconds.

The result should be equal to me unplugging the device, waiting a few seconds, and plugging it again.

What would I need to make such a circuit? Ideally, the timer should be easy to setup, have a display, and the circuit should be able to draw power from the USB cable, not requiring any form of external power.

Comment: I'm dying to know the context in which this would be useful to do :)

Comment: @vicatcu I am guessing the modem is USB powered and doing this will reset the modem. I have seen many cheap modems that seem to need to be reset randomly.

Comment: This question has a rather brainstorming-esque nature to it.  We generally avoid such questions.  If we can keep this discussion about how to overcome the troubles associated with switching high-speed differential signals, then it's probably fine.  If we're going to go off talking about all kinds of other solutions, like plugging your USB cable into a cheap USB hub and power-cycling the hub (easy), or setting up a `cron` job on the attached PC that automatically disables and re-enables the USB port, then this should go to our [chat] room.

Comment: Kevin, thank you for your comment. While I'm using other SE websites, EE is uncharted territory and I was in fact afraid of posting an inappropriate question. On the other hand, I am definitely not interested in power-cycling a hub, nor doing this with software (cron). I would appreciate any corrections that you might want to make in order to make my question better.

Comment: @vicatcu resetting cheap USB devices, especially many relatively unknown devices that I see in factory automation contexts. The USB modem is just one of the several that I see failing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a solution that is easily enough implemented [tm} without too much expert knowledge or experience you could use an off the shelf domestic event  timer and a relay.

(1) Time period generator

You can buy timers which are user settable and which count down to zero, sound an alarm for typically one minute then reset and start again. I have seen timers that behave exactly in this manner in retail outlets here in the past. Many timers do the count down part but not the reset and recycle so you'd need to be selective.

Many digital watches have an alarm that can be set to sound at the same time every day. Some also have repeating timers.

- The alarm has the advantage that you can set it at any time to sound at say midnight but they can not be set for say 23 hour cycles.
- The timer has the flexibility of any length of cycle but you need to start it at the start of a cycle (eg you need to be awake at midnight if you want the cycles to start from midnight.

Almost any microcontroller or an Arduino or whatever could be programmed for this task. Crystal control is desirable to allow reasonable time accuracy.

(2) USB blipper.

Once ypu have a timer triggering you could possible access a DC signal which activates a sounder but can for certain access the sound signal either by direct connection or using a microphone or piezo sounder disc used as a pickup. Once you have an audio signal you can use it to activate a relay either for the duration of the tone or for a one off period at the start or end of the tine. This could be done with a transistor or few or a pkg of opamps (eg LM324for

Any electronics including the timer could be powered by the USB +5V. The timer needs to be able to be run from +5V - some run from a 9V battery but will operate at 5V - this needs to be checked. Many operate from 1x AA or 2 x AA batteries and can easily be powered from 5V. Worst case you could make a 5V to 9V or whatever power supply but there should be enough timers available to allow a 5V capable one to be selected.

The Relay ideally should have  4 pole normally closed contacts (4PSTNC) but as little as a 1 pole normally closed will usually work.  4PSTCNC allows you to breal all 4 USB wires cleanly. Next best is breaking just power leads which will quite possibly achieve your aim. A single contact in one power lead will also quite likely work. I suggest 4PSTNC as worst case the modem may have a path to ground via equipment connected to it and just opening the power pair or one power lead MAY not do what you want. Testing is easy.

Once an adequate relay configuration is found, cut a USB extension cable in two (one or 2 or 4 conductors as require cut with the rest straight through) and route the cut wires via the relay contacts.

QED.

Comment: USB connectors are specifically designed to connect power prior to data, and disconnect data prior to power.  You might have undefined results if you choose to disconnect them "simultaneously" or if you only disconnect VBUS.  Though it would probably work...  Most of the time...

Answer (score 1):

Do you really want to open all the wires? Cutting the +5V should be enough, and that could be done with a solid-state relay controlled by a PIC or AVR, and that's practically all the components you need (except some resistors and capacitors, of course). The timing logic could be programmed in the uC with a lot of flexibility.

Comment: What about self powered USB devices?

Comment: In that case, you cut the +5V from the external power, not the +5V from the USB cable. Or, to be sure, cut both. You only need one more relay, and the smaller PIC/AVR would still have some I/O pins left.

Comment: Would be helpful for you to include that information in your answer.

Comment: @fceconel, would cutting the +5v (only) be a problem for the host device (the one providing power, and possibly exchanging data over the wire) ?

Comment: When you cut the power the device will put the D+/D- wires to high impedance, which the host will detect as a disconnection. Of course if that happens when data is exchanged something might be lost, but that wouldn't be a problem if the device is a modem, a BT dongle, etc. But if it's a storage device, that's another thing. In such cases the only safe alternative would be the disconnection controlled by the host, because only it knows when it's safe to do.